# CentOS 6 restrict user ssh access to his home folder

Tags: ssh, centos6, user-management, chroot

I am trying to restrict a newly added user to his homedir /home/username. Don't want him to be able to cd out of it.

I have this my sshd_config:

```
Match User username
       ChrootDirectory %h
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I set the owner of /home/username directory to root with chown, and set the permissions to 755.

Also added the user to chroot.conf.

Restarted sshd. But I get a connection closed by remote server when I try to login with the user.

**UPDATE:**

SSH output(edited out some info from it like IP address and RSA key):

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Mate/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to (IP address) [IP address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: Some key
debug1: Host 'IP address' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Mate/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Mate/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to IP address ([IP address]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to IP address closed by remote host.
Connection to IP address closed.
Transferred: sent 2400, received 2008 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10399.6, received 8701.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: chroot.conf? Try ssh -v username@server.example.net andd add the output to the question

Comment: What does the ssh log say?

Comment: Hi Guys! Thanks for the input. I updated the question with the ssh output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You've forced him to connect using only the sftp protocol, with `ForceCommand internal-sftp`. Unsurprisingly, that means he can't ssh in.

Comment: Hi Madhatter! Thanks for the input but even if I delete ForceCommand internal-sftp the problem is still there.

Comment: And you restarted `sshd` after the deletion?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it.